# Will creating a copy of a list based on a template, will the InfoPath be affected?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, infopath

I have a question regarding an associated InfoPath form of a list that I want to create a template of.    Do I have to do anything differently with the new InfoPath form associated with the newly created list?  One other SharePoint Developer stated that when they did this in the past, there was some kind of conflict between the InfoPath form on the new list...and it even affected the original list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is customized **SharePoint list form**, and if you create a template out of it, using if you create new list there won't be any issues, the list will be created as is like source infopath form list,I have done multiple times, there was no issues. Only thing we have to take care, if we had secondary data connection to different list in the source list, you need to change the data connection reference URL after creating the new list.

Comment: @hbibur-rahaman, Ok, I tested on our sandbox and it worked perfectly. Thanks!